Where behind the BOSE Wave Radio, do I plug the cable from the Creative T20 Series II left speaker?
I have a question about my Sound Design Stack Exchange post: Where behind the BOSE Wave Radio, do I plug the cable from the Creative T20 Series II left speaker?
Which Stack Exchange can I ask this on?

There is no Stack Exchange site suitable for your question. There are audio sites on the internet that will have the information you need.
